# Webmessenger, IM, Chat Clients - Jabber based? (like Facebook)

Tags: facebook, chat, xmpp

does anyone know a AJAX based chat client that connects to a Jabber server, and does the same things as Facebook or Netlog chatbar, plus Multi User Chat (MUC). 
I love the UI of cometchat.com/demo (left side of the chatbar is for MUC, right side Web-IM for my friends)

The only client I found until now is http://www.ijab.im/ - which is very new and doesn't speak MUC yet.

If anybody knows other libraries - thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using [strophejs](http://code.stanziq.com/strophe/) and the book [Professional XMPP with jquery and Javascript](http://professionalxmpp.com/) by Jack Moffitt.

strophejs is pretty much low level but very powerful, and the [book code samples](http://github.com/metajack/profxmpp) take you everywhere you want to go.

And, complementing Christopher's comment, [speeqe.com](http://speeqe.com/) is written in part by Moffitt and using strophejs !

Comment: I knew Strophe.js and speeqe, but somehow I missed the book and its examples. Excellent, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [speeqe.com](http://speeqe.com/) — "a web based, group chat client that works with the  XMPP/MUC protocol."

It's [open source](http://code.stanziq.com/speeqe/) too..